# CSS works, breaks on Chrome when moved to live MediaWiki

Tags: css, mediawiki

http://codepen.io/Drexl/pen/CBjdL

The above works just fine in both FF and Chrome. However when used on a live MedaWiki it fails on Chrome, works fine on FF.
This is the result when viewed in chrome:

http://i.imgur.com/0bALNzc.png (ignore the small edit I made).

Notice that it appears to be keeping the formatting, but the border is not present. I've used these border settings on other elements just fine which compounds my confusion.

Thanks for any advice/guidance you can provide! ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixes for border radius and box shadow, reading [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) source might help you understand CSS3 better..

Comment: The funny thing is that I've not used those prefixes at all for other things. I've used these same exact border settings and box shadow settings on other elements with no issues. Also, I just discovered that if I attempt to edit the MediaWiki page in chrome, and then cancel without saving the changes it displays properly.

Also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp shows that it is supported on all browsers without -webkit-. I checked that prior to posting. I just double checked now to make sure.

Comment: Sometimes they work without prefixes as well. However, there is no guarantee that it always will. always put the original code and prefixes after for CSS3. w3schools has too much outdated information and should not be confused with w3.org. -webkit- is just for Chrome and Safari so there is a logic error in your thinking.

Comment: I've made these changes. It doesn't really explain why the border and background color doesn't show up though. Also, I haven't applied them to the wiki yet but all of the places I put this code are suddenly working for everyone. This baffles me. I'll update the code on the wiki as well just to be safe.

Comment: I find that PPK's http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html is a far more reliable site for cross-site browser support. Also please see http://www.w3fools.com/